# Improving suggested edit does not require 2 approvals?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

I was reviewing an edit and had rejected the edit because it changed too much, and the suggester added "thanks in advance".  After hitting reject, I was promoted that [the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/767859) was already approved.

It would appear that when the approver decided to "improve" the edit, it effectively removes it from the suggested edit queue.  Is this expected behavior?

I realize that, as a 2K user, the approver/improver has unrestricted edit ability, so it seems logical that this would be possible, but it seems to circumvent the normal 2-approve-vote edit review process as the original suggester still received the +2 points for the suggested edit.

Comment: This is really status-by-design. It's not a bug. After all, as you say, you could have made the complete edit yourself without anything standing in your way. You don't really circumvent anything.

Comment: @Bart agreed, probably not a bug, but it seemed most appropriate of the required tags.  The issue I have is more than the improvement automatically approves a borderline suggested edit (borderline, at least in my limited experience) without 2 approvals (although in the end, the edit probably would have been improved by someone else if I rejected it.